# SonarQube different quality axis

Tags: sonarqube, metrics

My question is really simple , but i cant find anywhere this. I have the latest SonarQube version and for every language i got three different quality axis ( maybe based in the ISO 25010 standard), maintainability, security and reliability. But, in some tutorials i saw people with more categories as: performance, portability, usability... how can i get all this kind of analysis because i think that the rules are the same? is it a commercial set of rules? i dont know how to look , anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing in those tutorials is the SQALE model, which was basically dropped by SonarQube 5.6 in favor of the simpler, 3-axis model. In other words, those tutorials are pretty old, and if you really want what they're showing, you'll need to run a pretty old (4.x) version of SonarQube.

Your next question will likely be *why* the quality model changed in 5.6. The answer to that is that the SQALE model was really intricate and cool.... but on a day-to-day basis way too difficult to use. Which is why the current quality model breaks it down 3 ways:

Reliability / Bugs, Security / Vulnerabilities - things you should look at right away

Maintainability / Code Smells - everything else.